Multi-colored and multi-bar grouped charts
I have a Python script that automatically generates LaTeX codes that plot bar charts. An example of the generated code looks like:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{sfmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \centering
  \begin{axis}[
        ybar, axis on top,
        title={Performance charts},
        height=8cm, width=15.5cm,
        bar width=1.5cm,
        ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
        major grid style={draw=white},
        enlarge y limits={value=.1,upper},
        ymin=0, ymax=0.01,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        axis y line*=right,
        y axis line style={opacity=0},
        tickwidth=0pt,
        enlarge x limits=true,
        legend style={
            at={(0.5,-0.2)},
            anchor=north,
            legend columns=-1,
            /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}
        },
        ylabel={Time (seconds)},
        symbolic x coords={
           10,
           20,
       },
       xtick=data,
       nodes near coords={
        \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=3]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
       }
    ]
    \addplot+[ybar, fill=blue!50] plot coordinates {
      (10, 0.001223850250244141)
      (20, 0.001497483253479004)
    };
    \addplot+[ybar, fill=blue!25] plot coordinates {
      (10, 0.00045402050018310557)
      (20, 0.001987481117248536)
    };
    \addplot+[ybar, fill=red!50] plot coordinates {
      (10, 0.0008006999999999999)
      (20, 0.0010588)
    };
    \addplot+[ybar, fill=red!25] plot coordinates {
      (10, 0.0002661999999999997)
      (20, 0.0012075)
    };
    \legend{Real Time (Loading), Real-Time (Querying), CPU Time (Loading), CPU Time (Querying)}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

It produced this chart:
However, I want the two Real-Time bars to be stacked on themselves. The same as the CPU times. So that there are two bars per x-coordinate. The Python code that generated this latex code is:
def generate_latex_files(data, env_name, output_dir: Path) -> None:
    for key, values in data.items():
        if key[0] == env_name:
            # Sort values by graph size
            values.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

            # Calculate maximum value for ymax
            max_value = max(sum(val['loading'] + val['querying']) for _, val in values) * 1.1

            file_name = f'{key[1]}_{key[2]}.tex'
            full_file_name = output_dir / env_name / file_name
            full_file_name.parent.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
            with open(full_file_name, 'w') as f:
                f.write('\\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}\n')
                f.write('\\usepackage{pgfplots}\n')
                f.write('\\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}\n')
                f.write('\\usepackage{pgfplotstable}\n')
                f.write('\\renewcommand*{\\familydefault}{\\sfdefault}\n')
                f.write('\\usepackage{sfmath}\n')
                f.write('\\begin{document}\n')
                f.write('\\begin{tikzpicture}\n')
                f.write('  \\centering\n')
                f.write('  \\begin{axis}[\n')
                f.write('        ybar, axis on top,\n')
                f.write(f'        title={{Performance charts}},\n')
                f.write('        height=8cm, width=15.5cm,\n')
                f.write('        bar width=1.5cm,\n')
                f.write('        ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,\n')
                f.write('        major grid style={draw=white},\n')
                f.write('        enlarge y limits={value=.1,upper},\n')
                f.write(f'        ymin=0, ymax={max_value:.2f},\n')
                f.write('        axis x line*=bottom,\n')
                f.write('        axis y line*=right,\n')
                f.write('        y axis line style={opacity=0},\n')
                f.write('        tickwidth=0pt,\n')
                f.write('        enlarge x limits=true,\n')
                f.write('        legend style={\n')
                f.write('            at={(0.5,-0.2)},\n')
                f.write('            anchor=north,\n')
                f.write('            legend columns=-1,\n')
                f.write('            /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}\n')
                f.write('        },\n')
                f.write('        ylabel={Time (seconds)},\n')
                f.write('        symbolic x coords={\n')
                for value in values:
                    f.write(f'           {value[0]},\n')
                f.write('       },\n')
                f.write('       xtick=data,\n')
                f.write('       nodes near coords={\n')
                f.write('        \\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=3]{\\pgfplotspointmeta}\n')
                f.write('       }\n')
                f.write('    ]\n')

                # Real time plots
                f.write('    \\addplot+[ybar, fill=blue!50] plot coordinates {\n')
                for value in values:
                    f.write(f'      ({value[0]}, {value[1]["loading"][0]})\n')
                f.write('    };\n')
                f.write('    \\addplot+[ybar, fill=blue!25] plot coordinates {\n')
                for value in values:
                    f.write(f'      ({value[0]}, {value[1]["querying"][0]})\n')
                f.write('    };\n')

                # CPU time plots
                f.write('    \\addplot+[ybar, fill=red!50] plot coordinates {\n')
                for value in values:
                    f.write(f'      ({value[0]}, {value[1]["loading"][1]})\n')
                f.write('    };\n')
                f.write('    \\addplot+[ybar, fill=red!25] plot coordinates {\n')
                for value in values:
                    f.write(f'      ({value[0]}, {value[1]["querying"][1]})\n')
                f.write('    };\n')

                f.write('    \\legend{Real-Time (Loading), Real-Time (Querying), CPU Time (Loading), CPU Time (Querying)}\n')
                f.write('  \\end{axis}\n')
                f.write('\\end{tikzpicture}\n')
                f.write('\\end{document}\n')

The data being processed has this structure:
{
   (<env_name>, <graph_type>, <mode>): [(<graph_size>, {'loading': (<real_time>, <cpu_time>), 'querying': (<real_time>, <cpu_time>)}),...]
}

Is there a way I can achieve this? I have only been able to stack all the times with one bar.
Update: I want the Real-Time data to be stacked (loading at the bottom, querying at the top). The same applies to the CPU time as shown in this sketch.


Do you want to stack all 4 bars per time unit (load, load, cpu, cpu) ? Can you provide an example with 2-3 time points, together with an indication how the final diagram should look like? At least we need said data set, and, if your script does that, the LaTeX generated (it may or may not benefit from some changes). Thank you

Welcome to tex.sx.

@MS-SPO I have added a sample sketch. Thank you.

@barbarabeeton Thank you.

MS-SPO answer pointed me to Jake's solution which was used to generate this latex code:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\resetstackedplots{
   \pgfplots@stacked@isfirstplottrue
   \addplot [forget plot,draw=none] coordinates{(10,0) (20,0)};
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   ybar stacked,
   title={Performance charts},
   height=0.019\textheight, width=1.5\textwidth,
   bar width=0.8cm,
   ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
   major grid style={draw=gray!20},
   xtick=data,
   ymin=0,
   axis x line*=bottom,
   axis y line*=left,
   enlarge x limits=0.4,
   legend entries={
       Real Time (Loading),
       Real Time (Querying),
       CPU Time (Loading),
       CPU Time (Querying),
   },
   legend style={
       at={(0.5,-0.2)},
       anchor=north,
       legend columns=-1,
   },
   ylabel={Time (seconds)},
   xlabel={Graph Size},
   symbolic x coords={
           10,
           20,
       },
]
\addplot +[bar shift=-.5cm] coordinates {
    (10, 0.001223850250244141)
    (20, 0.001497483253479004)
};
\addplot +[bar shift=-.5cm] coordinates {
    (10, 0.00045402050018310557)
    (20, 0.001987481117248536)
};
\resetstackedplots
\addplot +[bar shift=.5cm] coordinates {
    (10, 0.0008006999999999999)
    (20, 0.0010588)
};
\addplot +[bar shift=.5cm] coordinates {
    (10, 0.0002661999999999997)
    (20, 0.0012075)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The code produced this chart:

It was dynamically generated by this Python function.

It seems to be some effort to put two stacked bar charts side by side. See e.g. this solution by Jake or that from Tom Bombadil.
So, unless you want to spend this effort, and time for debugging, I suggest to simply draw two diagrams from the same data source. For those interested, this concept change follows patterns of the Inventive Principles do-a-little-less, make-a-copy, at least.
Some remarks.
Data file
I assume a data structure like this:
 \begin{filecontents}{data2.dat}
 time  lrt lct  qrt qct
 10     5   4   3   3
 20     7   5   4   3
 30     4   7   5   2
 \end{filecontents}

Here the data are just included in the .tex file, while you can have just data3.dat etc in your directory and load that one, see below.
I'm assuming the first two columns belong together, just like the two last ones. If that's wrong, just change the y= assignments below.
\addplot-s
Plot column by column, e.g. here the 2nd one named lrt. replace the filename(s) with yours. Tell the program, the data contain a header.
    \addplot table[header=true,x=time,y=lrt]{data2.dat};% i.e. your data file

axis
Just for demo, if your title contains a comma, put everything inside of { }. The two bar-statements are needed. Put useful labels. The legend entries are just dummies: use better names.
   \begin{axis}[
        title={Real-time data, Load},   
        ybar stacked,
        stack plots=y,
        xmin=0, xmax=50,
        xlabel=time (s),
        ylabel=percent,
        legend entries={lrt, lct},% replace by better names
    ]

Suggested refinements ahead

move your datafile name into a \newcommand, replace in the \addplots, to change it in one place only
change the color schemes for both plots (see manual)
move the legend, e.g. outside (see manual)
adjust width and height of the diagrams to your needs
put them into an article class or similar, if that suits you; standalone just creates 2 images (see its manual)
find manuals at ctan, e.g. via search terms in your search engine ctan pgfplots
make sure your time intervals don't change, to avoid wrong visualization of data


\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
 % ~~~ pretending you have said file in your directory
 %     assuming lrt= load real timeetc.
 %     assuming, this is your data structure

 \begin{filecontents}{data2.dat}
 time  lrt lct  qrt qct
 10     5   4   3   3
 20     7   5   4   3
 30     4   7   5   2
 \end{filecontents}

 % ~~~ Concept: Draw two diagrams
 \begin{tikzpicture}    % LOAD
   \begin{axis}[
        title={Real-time data, Load},   
        ybar stacked,
        stack plots=y,
        xmin=0, xmax=50,
        xlabel=time (s),
        ylabel=percent,
        legend entries={lrt, lct},% replace by better names
    ]
    \addplot table[header=true,x=time,y=lrt]{data2.dat};% i.e. your data file
    \addplot table[header=true,x=time,y=lct]{data2.dat};    
   \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 
 % ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}    % CPU
   \begin{axis}[
        title={Real-time data, CPU},    
        ybar stacked,
        stack plots=y,
        xmin=0, xmax=50,
        xlabel=time (s),
        ylabel=percent,
        legend entries={qrt,qct},
    ]
    \addplot table[header=true,x=time,y=qrt]{data2.dat};
    \addplot table[header=true,x=time,y=qct]{data2.dat};
    
   \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

